# Menu/Page Zoom Out effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

There's this really cool effect I'd like to recreate, however I don't understand how the developer is achieving it. I've looked at the source - but I still don't quite understand.

The site is: http://drewwilson.com and below will be a couple of screenshots of what is happening.

When I click on the ellipsis on the header, a little about element pops up and the actual site 'zooms' backwards, leaving whitespace around it's border and greys out.

I can't see any javascript or jQuery doing it, so i'm assuming it's css?! - Although I might have missed something totally - so any help is appreciated :)

### **Inactivated**

[image: Just the plain site]

### **Activated**

[image: And the 'about' activated]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the whole page is wrapped in a div which have a 100% height and 100% width. So you have a control over everything inside that element.

You can achieve that by using css3 `transform: scale(value);` and of course `jQuery`

see samples [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/examples/l/bl-css-transformation-examples.htm#scale)

Comment: Ahhh, Yeah - didn't thing about that, now I feel stupid! Thanks so much!

Comment: Don't feel stupid just because you got down voted. And for whoever down voted you, I'd tried my best to share my ideas anyways.

Comment: Haha - not the down vote so much as the simplicity and obviousness of the answer...But thank you for your kind words anyway :)

Comment: haha...no problem, I'm just caught by your reaction. I'm sensitive in the expression `!` haha your welcome :)